# GCM interagindo com o google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Pessoal eu tenho uma função que server para atualizar o meu mapa na aplicação, ou seja, trocar o icones de posição e tal, porém eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte:

Quando eu recebesse uma mensagem do meu GCM, por exemplo "Atualizar", gostaria que fosse chamado a função de atualizar o meu mapa. Claro que preciso verificar se a tela do mapa está aberta e tudo mais, porém não sei como fazer.

Eu simplesmente fiz no `onMessage` chamar minha função, porém da erro, falando que não estou na UI Thread alguem sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando vc utiliza o GCM, vc declara seu `GcmIntentService` e seu `GcmBroadCastReceiver` como descrito [AQUI](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

Mas você pode, também, declarar um BroadCastReceiver na sua Activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver GcmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // chama seu método para atualizar o googleMaps
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        registerReceiver(GcmReceiver, new IntentFilter(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE));
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(GcmReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

(Só para avisar, o método `GCMBaseIntentService.onMessage()` está obsoleto (*deprecated*), no lugar dele deve-se usar um broadcast receiver apropriado e registrar-se junto ao servidor GCM com a classe [GoogleCloudMessaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)).

Com relação ao seu problema, lance um *broadcast* no método que recebe a mensagem (no seu caso, `onMessage()` mesmo) e faça a tela do seu mapa receber o *broadcast*.

***Se*** por acaso ocorrer o erro que diz que você não está na *UI Thread*, execute o trecho de código que lança o *broadcast* no *UI Thread* com a ajuda de um *handler*, assim:

```
public onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

    new Handler(Loooper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent outroIntent = ...
            context.sendBroadcast(outroIntent); // Obs.: não confunda o intent recebido com
                                                // o intent que você quer mandar no broadcast
        }
    });
}
```